# Activator.CreateInstance(Type T) returns null

Tags: c#, reflection, interface, null, createinstance

EDIT: This code runs as a custom inspector code in unity, but I am not sure if it is relevant, if it is, I will post the entire class.

I want to get all classes that implements a specific interface, and show an options list so a user can choose how to implement the interface.

It is a simple interface that describes the character behavior.

I have tried to replace the Interface with an abstract class, but for no avail...

In the debug I can see, that the returned values is null.

All I have found online says that the type might not exist, but it is impossible in my case, because I get my type using reflection.

```
ICombatBehaviour combat;
private string[] FindAllCombatOptions(out List<Type> existingTypes)
{
    List<string> options = new List<string>();
    existingTypes = new List<Type>();
    var combatBehaviours = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ICombatBehaviour)).GetTypes()
        .Where(myType => myType.IsClass && !myType.IsAbstract && typeof(ICombatBehaviour).IsAssignableFrom(myType));
    foreach (var behaviour in combatBehaviours)
    {
        existingTypes.Add(behaviour);
        options.Add(behaviour.Name);
    }
    return options.ToArray();
}
private void UpdateType(List<Type> types)
{
    combat = Activator.CreateInstance(types[index]) as ICombatBehaviour;
}
```

The `UpdateType()` method, gets all the types that `FindAllCombatOptions()` method has found, and takes the type in the selected index. The type is correct, but the `combat` variable remains null...

The ICombatBehavior:

```
public interface ICombatBehaviour
{

}
```

The Implementing classes:

```
public class FightBehaviour : ICombatBehaviour
{

}

public class EscapeBehaviour : ICombatBehaviour
{

}
```

This is the calling function:

```
public override void SelectType()
    {
        List<Type> types;
        string[] options = FindAllCombatOptions(out types);
        index = AskUserForAType(options); // Currently returns only zero
        UpdateType(types);
    }
```

Comment: The code that you've posted seems to work fine, as seen [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wlbZlr). Given that, it might help if you share some more code, such as the entire class where these members are defined, how they are used, and an example of a type that implements `ICombatBehaviour`

Comment: Are you sure, that the type on that index implements ICombatBehaviour?

Comment: @OndřejKubíček I am sure, because as you can see the method FindAllCombatOptions() finds only classes that implement that interface

Comment: What is the type in `types[index]`?  Please share its type declaration.

Comment: I have added a code for the classes

Comment: Okay, thanks, and what type is in `types[index]`?

Comment: Do you have `ICombatBehaviour` defined multiple times, e.g. defined in two separate assemblies?  Two identical interfaces in separate assemblies are not considered the same interface.

Comment: types[index] is a System.Type, if I check it in debug mode, I get that it is correct (either FightBehaviour or EscapeBehaviour, depends on the index value). I don't have another Interface named ICombatBehavior in my project

Comment: You should change `Activator.CreateInstance(…) as ICombatBehaviour` to `(ICombatBehaviour)Activator.CreateInstance(…)`, because you expect all of your types at this point to derive from ICombatBehaviour. If there is a type who doesn’t derive from it it will throw an exception and tell you what went wrong instead of silently failing with null and you don’t know why like it currently does.

Comment: It changed nothing, according to the debug the Activator.CreateInstance(…) is null, the casting is not related

Comment: @user9977758 I dont see how you call your UpdateType so I can't know anything about content of that list. But there is another option I get in mind. That Assembly.GetAssembly() will load another assembly than the current one in application. Can you examine the types for ".Module.FullyQualifiedName"?

Comment: The ".Module.FullyQualifiedName" value is: "D:\\Documents\\Unity Projects\\2018\\Tower Defence Game\\Library\\ScriptAssemblies\\Assembly-CSharp.dll"

Comment: @user9977758 That's getting realy interesting. Can you try to improve yout UpdateType method like this: "`combat = types[index].GetConstructors()[0].Invoke(null) as ICombatBehaviour;`"? I see you have no constructor defined, so you should have only one. Or is it possible to send all code so I could experiment with it?

Comment: I have finally made this work, it was something related to unity. I needed to change some settings. Thanks for the help.

now I can create a dynamic and easily changeable  program.

the last comment with the constructor was the thing that made me realize that. Thanks again for you time and help, Highly appreciate it

Comment: You are welcome. You can add an answer and accept it so the newcomers with the same issue could easily find a solution without reading all the comments. :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple. The problem was not in the code, but in Unity3D.

Unity created the classes `FightBehaviour` and `EscapeBehaviour` as a MonoBehaviour class, which can not be instantiated.  Therefore I needed to set it to a normal class.

Thanks for everyone in the comments that helped me, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Please load all the assemblies before creating type in UpdateType method.

```
private void UpdateType(List<Type> types)
{
    for(int index =0; index < types.Count; index++)
    {
          Assembly.Load(types[index].Assembly.FullName);
          combat = Activator.CreateInstance(types[index]) as ICombatBehaviour;

    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I get an error that there is not such overload Assembly.Load(Assembly)...

Comment: I forgot to add fullName property.  This should work now.

Comment: Nope, I still got a null value…
I don't understand why it doesn't work....

Comment: Did you check if the type which you are sending in  ' types[index] ' is assignable To ICombatBehavior ?  I believe then the type is not inheriting from the ICombatBehavior.